# How can we find the volume of the intersection of the two tetrahedra TABC and T'A'B'C'?

Tags: geometry

$TABC$ is a tetrahedron with volume $1$.

$G$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$, and $O$ is the midpoint of $TG$.

Reflect $TABC$ with respect to $O$ to get $T'A'B'C'$.

How can we find the volume of the intersection between $TABC$ and $T'A'B'C'$?

Comment: You should start mentioning what you have thought and done about the problems you are proposing. The purpose of this community is not to solve homeworks for free, but to share knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the affine maps preserves the ratio between volumes, we are free to assume that:
$$A=(0,0,0),\quad B=(1,0,0),\quad C=(0,1,0),\quad T=(0,0,1),$$
from which $G=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0)$ and $O=(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2})$.

The intersection between the two tetrahedra is so the set:
$$E=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:0\leq x,y\leq \frac{1}{3},0\leq z\leq 1,\frac{2}{3}\leq x+y+z\leq 1\}.$$
Using the notation $\mathbb{1}_J$ for the indicator function of the interval $J$, we have that the volume of $ABCT$ is given by:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x+y+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{1}{6},$$
while:
$$\mu(E)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1/3}\int_{0}^{1/3}\mathbb{1}_{[2/3,1]}(x+y+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{1}{27},$$
so the volume of the intersection is always $\frac{2}{9}$ of the volume of the original tetrahedron.